# Templated if fails with compiler error error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)

Tags: c++, templates

If I compile the following code with gcc

```
namespace TMP {
    // template to choose type depending on boolean condition
    template <bool condition, typename x, typename y> struct if_t                               { typedef y type; };
    template <                typename x, typename y> struct if_t<true, typename x, typename y> { typedef x type; };

}

TMP::if_t<false, uint8_t, uint16_t>::type test;
```

I get an error message

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
```

If I remove the second template it will compile successfully. However I thought that my code is almost the same as in the book [wikibook example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Templates/Template_Meta-Programming#Example:_Compile-time_.22If.22). What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, just remove redundant typename. compiled with gcc 4.9.2.

```
namespace TMP {
    // template to choose type depending on boolean condition
    template <bool condition, typename x, typename y>
    struct if_t
    {
        typedef y type;
    };
    template <typename x, typename y>
    struct if_t < true, x, y >
    {
        typedef x type;
    };

}
```

Comment: I changed it and now I get `error: 'type' in 'struct Internal::TMP::if_t<false, unsigned char, unsigned int>' does not name a type
         TMP::if_t<false, uint8_t, uint16_t>::type test;` Do you have any suggestion why this fails?

Comment: Argh, I found out on my own. If I want a type I should typedef it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of yufeng I found out how it should have been done:

```
namespace TMP {
    // template to choose type depending on boolean condition
    template <bool condition, typename x, typename y> 
        struct if_t { typedef y type; };
    template <typename x, typename y> 
        struct if_t<true, typename x, typename y> { typedef x type; };
}

TMP::if_t<false, uint8_t, uint16_t>::type test;
```